# How can I remove shower head

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, shower

I would like to change the shower head from my bathroom as this old one shoots the water in an annoying single stream due to missing parts.

The previous owner have done a terrible job putting this shower head, first of all there was only one screw in it (which I've removed) and also it looks like they've put silicone everywhere under it where screws were suppose to go.

How can I safely remove this? I tried turning it anti-clockwise with bare hands, but no success. Any suggestions are welcome.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just bare hands seldom will work, unless very lucky.  Usually need a rubber strap wrench if wanting no damage, or a pipe wrench if changing for a new one.  Check carefully for hidden lock screws, might be behind a cap hiding a hole.

Comment: No matter what tool you use, the silicone will resist the turning effort. It will help your cause immensely to use a sharp utility-type knife to cut through as much of the silicone as possible. Also, if you have access to the back side of the wall, you might find that there's a fitting behind the wall that you can have someone hold with one wrench while you use another one on this side of the wall.

Comment: Flange outside is just cover. Lime may be built into connection. Try to apply acetic acid into connection.  If it does not work, cut the pipe and use some left drilling bit, CCW rotation.

Comment: Perhaps you want to change the whole arm but if the problem you want to solve is a new spray head that sprays correctly, perhaps it is possible to just remove the spray head?  Did you try?  Can you move the flange away and post a picture of where the head meats the arm?  It's easy to buy replacement head.

Comment: I'm happy you got this resolved and appreciate that you came back to share your results. If you'll take the [tour], you'll see that in this "Question & Answer" format, editing your resolution into the question isn't the appropriate thing to do. Please copy/paste your "edit" into the "Answer" box down below - self-answered questions are appropriate and acceptable here.

Comment: Thank you @FreeMan for your comment, I've done it in the way you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I've managed to unstick it from the wall with brute force, the whole head shower arm was just placed on the top of the pipe and the silicon was the only thing holding it back. Although you can see that it can screw inside of the pipe, this was not the case.

[image]
[image]