# What shower head to install?

Tags: shower, pipe

This question is a follow-up question after my previous post from [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/236144/how-can-i-remove-shower-head). So basically after I have removed the old shower head, I've been left off with this pipe coming out of the wall, what replacement shower head I can put in here? I've been to 4 different stores and nobody was able to help me out, they all said I need to change the fitting somehow and I need a plumber for this.
Note: The old showerhead was just placed on top of the pipe and glued to the wall with silicone.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: might be easiest to replace the pipe from the nearest juncture (or cut and weld a new pipe on). The only other thing I can think of is to find a mtm adapter piece that matches the female threads in that pipe. Without knowing the thread pitch it would be guesswork at best. Remember to tape in the tightening direction.

Comment: Dig the caulk out of the hole so we can see the 1/2" NPT drop ear brass elbow that's back there. If so, you need a close nipple or a very short nipple, a rag so you don't scratch it, a wrench, and a roll of tape; not a plumber.